# How can I install MSBuild 17 on a Windows Server?

Tags: installation, msbuild

I'm trying to install MSBuild 17 on a Windows server (Windows Server 2016) that'll be used in a CI/CD pipeline.  Supposedly MS Build 17 is installed as part of the installation of the .NET 6 SDK but I've not found that to be the case. It's also installed as part of the VS 2022 Build Tools download but that installer requires an internet connection and the target Windows Server has no internet connection.

Can anyone suggest any other way of installing MSBuild 17 on a Windows Server?

Comment: MSBuild is hosted within the dotnet command line tool that is installed as part of the SDK. The `dotnet build` command is using MSBuild and the [`dotnet msbuild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild) command gives full access. Note that the SDK can't build .NET Framewok projects.

Comment: If you need to build .NET Framework projects, an offline installer can be created for the VS 2022 Build Tools. See "[Create an offline installation package of Visual Studio for local installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)" and "[Visual Studio 2022 build tools](https://superuser.com/questions/1749638/visual-studio-2022-build-tools)".

Comment: Thanks @JonathanDodds for the link to the offline installation package creation link, I thought there must be a way to it (like the offline Office 2016 and beyond installation package creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to install the build tools by creating an off-line installation folder using the downloaded vs_BuildTools.exe on a desktop machine (which has internet access) as follows:

```
vs_BuildTools.exe --layout c:\dev\vs2022-build-tools-installer --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --includeRecommended --includeOptional
```

I copied the output folder (size about 7GB) as specified by the --layout argument to my server and ran the command:

```
vs_BuildTools.exe --noweb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --includeRecommended
```

From the resulting dialog for choosing which components will be installed, I made sure .NET SDK was ticked before hitting Install, after a number of long minutes everything successfully installed.

I've verified that MSBuild 17 was installed and works fine, the only thing left to do is configure the .NET project/solution I'm trying to build so that the Nuget packages are downloaded from a local Nuget package host rather than the remote nuget.org (any advice on that would be welcomed.

Comment: NuGet can use a folder or file share as a package source. You don't need a private NuGet server running locally. The 'tricky' part is fixing up the package host configuration when the source control repo has a NuGet.Config file that is already configuring a package host.